# UITableViewCell's backgroundView overlapping contentView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I am trying to set the backgroundView parameter of a UITableViewCell, but the backgroundView is overlapping the bounds of the cell. I have tried setting masksToBounds to YES, but that doesn't seem to make a difference. Please can you tell me where I am going wrong?

Here is an image showing my problem:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
UIImageView *iv = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame] autorelease];
[iv setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"paper"]];
[iv.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
[cell.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
[cell.contentView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
[cell setBackgroundView:iv];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `masksToBounds` doesn't work because the bounds of the cell are a rectangle.

Even if the corners of the cell are rounded, they're still part of the cell (but they contain transparent pixels). When a cell is displayed in a grouped table view, its background view (and its selected background view) is drawn in regard of its position in its section (middle, top, bottom, single).

So, if you want to provide a custom background view, you need to compute the position of the cell in its section and provide the adequate background :

- either by using 4 different images
- or by using the mask property of the background image's layer
- or by subclassing UIView and implementing drawRect: so the graphic context is clipped before the image is drawn.

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting every cell that background view, if so why don't you just set it to the table view background.